# How to generate routes based on file tree (like Nuxt.js) for vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Nuxt.js generates its routes based on file tree.

[Snnipets from the official page:](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing)

```
pages/
--| _slug/
-----| comments.vue
-----| index.vue
--| users/
-----| _id.vue
--| index.vue
```

From which Nuxt.js generates:

```
router: {
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'index',
      path: '/',
      component: 'pages/index.vue'
    },
    {
      name: 'users-id',
      path: '/users/:id?',
      component: 'pages/users/_id.vue'
    },
    {
      name: 'slug',
      path: '/:slug',
      component: 'pages/_slug/index.vue'
    },
    {
      name: 'slug-comments',
      path: '/:slug/comments',
      component: 'pages/_slug/comments.vue'
    }
  ]
}
```

I think this feature is really cool (in fact it's pretty common for standard MVC frameworks, as you know). Without this, managing the routes and components quickly becomes a mess as the project grows.

Is it possible to make this work without Nuxt.js, or specifically in my case, when using vue-cli webpack template?

Comment: Sure, just do whatever Nuxt does ~ https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js

Comment: Well, sure, but I think that directly tweaking the Nuxt codebase is just too hacky for such a "basic" task.